# Why does the fuse blow when I turn on the oven and stove in the kitchen?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, kitchens, new-home

Why does the fuse blow when I turn on the oven and stove in the kitchen?

This is a new build house that I rent. The owners told us we can only use either the oven (countertop oven) or stove (countertop stove) at a time. If we use both at the same time the fuse blows.

Does anyone know what we can do about it or in what way the house was build that this situation exists?

Comment: Not use both at the same time, or move one to a different circuit.  It seems weird on a new built that this happens.  Older houses had this problem when plugging in a toaster and kettle on the same outlet.  You learnt to use one at a time or move one to another circuit.  Newer code is suppose to limit this in kitchens, bigger circuits and more of them.  I would check the electrical permit for the building.  As renters you can't do much.

Comment: Where in the world is this? Rules differ in different locations. Given you mention "fuses" for a new-build house the location may be a bit behind the usual rules.

Comment: Are they plugged in or does the power cable go into a box?  Your location in the world will help also, so we know what code you are under.

Comment: Does the fuse actually blow? Or are they telling you "don't do this, because it *will* blow?" Big difference. Also, is it a fuse (requires physical replacement) or is a circuit breaker (flip the handle to reset)?

Comment: Are the counter top oven and stove sitting on the counter top and plugged into a regular 120 V receptacle? If so, are they plugged into the same receptacle? Putting one of them on a different circuit should solve the problem. Best to move one of them to a location where its cord will reach a receptacle on a different circuit, but if that is not possible, then you could use a 15 A or 20 A extension cord.

Comment: Can you move one or the other to a different location so that they can be plugged into different circuits? If so, that would eliminate the "can't use both at the same time" problem. However, it might cause issues on the new circuit, depending on what other loads are on it...

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the fuse blow when I turn on the oven and stove in the kitchen?

Because the fuse amperage is insufficient for both devices to run at the same time

> Does anyone know what we can do about it or in what way the house was build that this situation exists?

Without looking at the wiring, it is impossible to know.  However, it is likely due to the way that the house is built, and there is nothing you can do about it as renters, other than not using both at the same time.  As both devices are countertop devices, you can also try different combinations of receptacles so that they're not on the same circuit.

Comment: Just to ensure it's clear for the OP: While "the fuse amperage is insufficient" is obviously true, the solution is **_NOT_** to put in a bigger fuse - that will, most likely, lead to fire!

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with preheating the oven, turning it off, getting one ring of the  stovetop hot, and once it's not running all the time, turning the oven back on.  This relies on the typical behaviour that most ovens and stove burners don't run for a large fraction of the time once they've warmed up.  (Modern) ovens in particular hold heat well if the door is shut, so can cook without power for a good few minutes